# Python BeautifulSoup output unusual spacing and characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im new to python.

Im trying to parse data from a website using BeautifulSoup, I have successful used BeautifulSoup before. However for this particular website the data returned has spaces between every character and  lots of "&gt" characters as well.

The weird thing is if copy the page source and add it to my local apache instance and make a request to my local copy, then the output is perfect. I should mention that the difference between my local and the website:

1. my local does not use https
2. my local does not require authentication however the website does require Active Directory auth and I using  requests_ntlm

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://WEBSITE/CONTEXT/",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\USER','PASS'))
content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like local server returns content encoded using UTF-8 and the main website use UTF-16. It's suggests the main website in not configured correctly. However it's possible to get around this issue with code.

Python defaults the requests to the encoding to UTF-8. (I believe) this is based on the response headers. The request has a method called *apparent_encoding*, which reads the stream and detects the correct encoding using *chardet*. However apparent_encoding does not get consumed, unless specified.

Therefore by setting *r.encoding* = *r.apparent_encoding*, the request should download the text correctly across both environments.

Code should look something like:

```
r = requests.get("http://WEBSITE/CONTEXT/",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\USER','PASS'))
r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding # Override the default encoding
content = r.text
r.raise_for_status() # Always check for server errors before consuming the data.
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml') 
print(soup.prettify()) # Should match print(content) (minus indentation)
```

Comment: Hi @Greg

It seems like the request.get content is the issue.


This is what I see , 


If i print out the request.get return content it looks fine, however if I pipe it to a file it looks very weird every second string has an @ character

```��<^@!^@D^@O^@C^@T^@Y^@P^@E^@ ^@h^@t^@m^@l^@```

I have tried the ```.encoding = 'utf-8'``` but the output is still the same

Comment: The next step will be to examine the response headers. After the requests.get() add print(r.headers). This should give us a clue as to what the server is returning. Also I believe you said the URL works in a web browser. If you check view source, does it have a meta html tag with attribute charset?

Comment: Yes web browser works and when I view source it looks correct , does not have the other characters 

Here is the header output

{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 10 Jun 2020 13:38:13 GMT', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'ETag': '"9d5abb632c3fd61:0"', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'Persistent-Auth': 'true', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Wed, 10 Jun 2020 14:08:18 GMT', 'Content-Length': '5557948'}

Comment: That's interesting the web browser will make the same request and somehow know to display the content. The headers themselves doen't give any clue as to what encoding type (other than default).The next thing we can examine is checking (on 3 lines) print(f"encoding: {r.encoding}") print(f"apparent_encoding: {r.apparent_encoding}") print(f"content: {r.content}") # Does this contain html?

Comment: If would be interesting to see if the headers were different to your local version. I would have expected headers to have something like {content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}

Comment: output of above 3 prints 1. encoding: UTF-8
2. apparent_encoding: UTF-16 3. Is a bunch of hex here is a snippent content: b'\xff\xfe<\x00...     Lastly this is the header from local {'Date': 'Thu, 11 Jun 2020 08:23:35 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.43 (Fedora)', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 10 Jun 2020 10:20:35 GMT', 'ETag': '"2a2dfa-5a7b831db4f63"', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': '2764282', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}

Comment: Your local version works fine because it'returns content-type as 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'. Where as the other server doesn't. It's encoding as UTF-8 but it looks like its UTF-16. One thing you can try is r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding and then print out r.text and r.content. Also another thing you could try is running the api via postman.

Comment: Finally it's working now. The  r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding  resolved the issue. So now I have this line r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding followed by content = r.text . @Greg thanks for you assistance and patience , I truly appreciate the help

Comment: that's great news, I've updated the answer for completeness.